# How can i add print feature to jsgrid

Tags: jsgrid

I am using js-grid as my grid and i want to enable the print functionality just like datatables (https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/print/simple.html).

I searched js-grid and found nothing about the print functionality. How can i add this feature to js-grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a separate page, add jsGrid with the same data on it with simplified printing-friendly styling (turn off editing and filtering etc).

On the body of this page open print dialog:

```
<body onload="window.print()">
...
</body>
```

Then add a button that will open this new page in a new tab.

Comment: This worked for me. But i still see this as a workaround. If jsGrid can ship this feature by default then that would be great.